# Nested 'if checkbox is checked' throws an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need a string to be modified whenever any of checkboxes are checked/unchecked but only the first checkbox does the job when others throw me an exception error: 
" "#two-stars".is is not a function ". I've tried different conditions but it seems something is wrong at the very core of this code which I wasn't been able to find yet. Code:

```
$('#input:checkbox').change(function(){

        starsQueries = '';
        if( $('#two-stars').is(':checked') ){
            starsQueries += '&stars=401';
            console.log('checked!');
        }
        if( $('#three-stars').is(':checked') ){
            if( ('#two-stars').is(':checked') ){
                starsQueries += ',402';
            } else {
                starsQueries += '&stars=402';
            }
        }
        if( $('#four-stars').is(':checked') ){
            if( ('#three-stars').is(':checked') || ('#two-stars').is(':checked') ){
                starsQueries += ',403';
            } else {
                starsQueries += '&stars=403';
            }
        }
        if( $('#five-stars').is(':checked') ){
            if( ('#four-stars').is(':checked') || ('#three-stars').is(':checked') || ('#two-stars').is(':checked') ){
                starsQueries += ',404';
            } else {
                starsQueries += '&stars=404';
            }
        }
});
```

On JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4mLcz6mt/1/

Comment: Code seems overly complicated, but if you looked at your code closely you can see your copy/paste error all over.

Comment: missing some jquery's there (i.e. `$`)

Comment: Make your life easier to maintain, get rid of all those ifs https://jsfiddle.net/vf9L1cko/

Answer (score 1):

You have ommited `$` in front of `('#two-stars')`, `('#three-stars')` and `('#four-stars')`

Check https://jsfiddle.net/4mLcz6mt/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery object `$` in five places. The JQuery always need `$` to procees correctly.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
  
starsQueries = '';
if( $('#two-stars').is(':checked') ){
  starsQueries += '&stars=401';
  console.log('checked!');
  $('#test').append('2* checked<br>');
}
if( $('#three-stars').is(':checked') ){
  if( $('#two-stars').is(':checked') ){
    starsQueries += ',402';
  } else {
    starsQueries += '&stars=402';
  }
  $('#test').append('3* checked<br>');
}
if( $('#four-stars').is(':checked') ){
  if( $('#three-stars').is(':checked') || $('#two-stars').is(':checked') ){
    starsQueries += ',403';
  } else {
    starsQueries += '&stars=403';
  }
  $('#test').append('4* checked<br>');
}
if( $('#five-stars').is(':checked') ){
  if( $('#four-stars').is(':checked') || $('#three-stars').is(':checked') || $('#two-stars').is(':checked') ){
    starsQueries += ',404';
  } else {
    starsQueries += '&stars=404';
  }
  $('#test').append('5* checked<br>');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="two-stars" id="two-stars">
  <label for="two-stars">2*</label>
  <br>
  
  <input type="checkbox" name="three-stars" id="three-stars">
  <label for="three-stars">3*</label>
  <br>
  
  <input type="checkbox" name="four-stars" id="four-stars">
  <label for="four-stars">4*</label> 
  <br>
  
  <input type="checkbox" name="five-stars" id="five-stars">
  <label for="five-stars">5*</label>
    
    <div id='test'>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$( selector )` not `( selector )` and if you are doing star ratings consider using radio buttons instead for mutually-exclusive options. Also, data binding will be of help here. To wit:

```js
$(".star_rater").each(function() {
  var min = $(this).data("minstars") || 1,
    max = $(this).data("maxstars") || 3,
    name = $(this).data("formname"),
    curVal = $(this).data("stars");
  if (max > min) {
    var html = [];
    for (i = 0; i < max - min + 1; i++) {
      var val = min + i,
        id = name + val.toString();
      html.push('<input type="radio" name="');
      // insure all radios for this rater are in same group
      html.push(name);
      html.push('" id="');
      html.push(id);
      html.push('" value="');
      html.push(val);
      html.push('"');
      if (val === curVal) {
        html.push(' checked');
      }
      html.push('/>');
      html.push('<label for="');
      html.push(id);
      html.push('">');
      html.push(val);
      html.push('</label>');
    }
  }
  $(this).html(html.join(""));
}).on("change", function() {
  var name = $(this).data("formname"),
    val = $(this).children("input:checked").val();
  $("#output").text([name, val].join("="));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Default has 1-3 stars
<div class="star_rater" data-formname="rater1"></div>
Optional extend max stars to 5
<div class="star_rater" data-maxstars="5" data-formname="rater2"></div>
Range options 5 to 10 (with default = 7)
<div class="star_rater" data-maxstars="10" data-minstars="5" data-stars="7" data-formname="rater3"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```